# Does .parse anchor or :sigspace first in a Perl 6 rule?

Tags: grammar, raku

I have two questions. Is the behavior I show correct, and if so, is it documented somewhere?

I was playing with the grammar `TOP` method. Declared as a `rule`, it implies beginning- and end-of-string anchors along with `:sigspace`:

```
grammar Number {
    rule TOP { \d+ }
    }

my @strings = '137', '137 ', ' 137 ';

for @strings -> $string {
    my $result = Number.parse( $string );
    given $result {
        when Match { put "<$string> worked!" }
        when Any   { put "<$string> failed!" }
        }
    }
```

With no whitespace or trailing whitespace only, the string parses. With leading whitespace, it fails:

```
<137> worked!
<137 > worked!
< 137 > failed!
```

I figure this means that `rule` is applying `:sigspace` first and the anchors afterward:

```
grammar Foo {
    regex TOP { ^ :sigspace \d+ $ }
    }
```

I expected a `rule` to allow leading whitespace, which would happen if you switched the order:

```
grammar Foo {
    regex TOP { :sigspace ^  \d+ $ }
    }
```

I could add an explicit token in `rule` for the beginning of the string:

```
grammar Number {
    rule TOP { ^ \d+ }
    }
```

Now everything works:

```
<137> worked!
<137 > worked!
< 137 > worked!
```

I don't have any reason to think it should be one way or the other. The [Grammars docs](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars) say two things happen, but the docs do not say which order these effects apply:

> Note that if you're parsing with .parse method, token TOP is automatically anchored

and

> When rule instead of token is used, any whitespace after an atom is turned into a non-capturing call to ws.

---

I think the answer is that the rule isn't actually anchored in the pattern sense. It's the way `.parse` works. The cursor has to start at position 0 and end at the last position in the string. That's something outside of the pattern.

Comment: cf https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-12-17#i_13756072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't two regex effects going on. The `rule` applies `:sigspace`. After that, the grammar is defined. When you call `.parse`, it starts at the beginning of the string and goes to the end (or fails). That anchoring isn't part of the grammar. It's part of how `.parse` applies the grammar.

My main issue was the odd way some of the things are worded in the docs. They aren't technically wrong, but they also tend to assume knowledge about things the reader might not know. In this case, the casual comment about anchoring `TOP` isn't as special as it seems. Any rule passed to `.parse` is anchored in the same way. There's no special behavior for that rule name other than it's the default value for `:rule` in a call to `.parse`.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is intended, and is a culmination of these language features:

- **Sigspace ignores whitespace before the first atom.**

  From the design docs<sup>1</sup> ([S05: Regexes and Rules, line 348](http://design.perl6.org/S05.html#line_348), emphasis added):

  > The new :s (:sigspace) modifier causes certain whitespace sequences to be considered "significant"; they are replaced by a whitespace matching rule, . Only whitespace sequences immediately following a matching construct (atom, quantified atom, or assertion) are eligible. **Initial whitespace is ignored at the front of any regex**, to make it easy to write rules that can participate in longest-token-matching alternations. **Trailing space inside the regex delimiters is significant.**

  This means:

  ```
  rule TOP { \d+ }
                ^-------- <.ws> automatically inserted

  rule TOP { ^ \d+ $ }
              ^---^-^---- <.ws> automatically inserted
  ```
- **Regexes are first-class compiled code with lexical scoping.**

  A regex/rule is not a string that may have characters concatenated to it later to change its behavior. It is a self-contained routine, which is parsed and has its behavior nailed down at compile time.

  Regex modifiers like `:sigspace`, including the one implicitly added by the `rule` keyword, apply only to their lexical scope - i.e. to the fragment of source code they appear in at compile time. [S05, line 629](http://design.perl6.org/S05.html#line_629)<sup>1</sup>:

  > The :i, :m, :r, :s, :dba, :Perl5, and Unicode-level modifiers can be placed inside the regex (and are lexically scoped)
- **The anchoring of `rule TOP` is done at run time by `.parse`.**

  [S05, line 4423](http://design.perl6.org/S05.html#line_4423)<sup>1</sup>:

  > The .parse and .parsefile methods anchor to the beginning and ending of the text, and fail if the end of text is not reached. (The TOP rule can check against $ itself if it wishes to produce its own error message.)

  I.e. the anchoring to the beginning of the string is not intrinsic to the rule `TOP`, and doesn't affect how the lexical scope of `TOP` is parsed and compiled. It is done when method `.parse` is called.

  It has to be this way, because because the same grammar can be used with different starting rules instead of `TOP`, using `.parse(..., rule => ...)`.

So when you write

```
rule TOP { \d+ }
```

it is compiled as

```
regex TOP { :r \d+ <.ws> }
```

And when you `.parse` that grammar, it effectively invokes the regex code `^ <TOP> $`, with the anchors not being part of `TOP`'s lexical scope but rather of a scope that merely *calls* the routine `TOP`. The combined behavior is as if the rule `TOP` had been written as:

```
regex TOP { ^ [:r :s \d+] $ }
```

---

<sup>1) The design docs are in general not to be taken as gospel for what is or isn't part of the Perl 6 language, but S05 is pretty accurate in that regard, except that it mentions some features that haven't been implemented yet but are planned. Anyone who wants to truly grok the intricacies of Perl 6 regexes/grammars, is IMO well served by reading the full S05 from top to bottom at least once.</sup>

Comment: As I noted in my question, I was asking something slightly different about the ordering of two different effects. I think the docs are misleading with the use of "anchor" here, since that's pattern jargon.

Comment: @briandfoy: I rewrote the answer.

Comment: Yeah, still things I wasn't asking about. Thanks for helping, but I think you're basically saying what I said at the end of my question. And, the grammar section of S05 is quite short. ;)

Comment: Yes, your last paragraph is basically right, except that one could debate whether it's really that unreasonable to refer to `^ <TOP> $` behavior as "TOP is automatically anchored". Semantics, I guess. I was hoping my rewritten answer might help you understand why it *has* to behave that way. The fact that the "order" in which the two effects apply is the natural result of documented language features, is the reason why it isn't specifically documented anywhere, and also the reason why I initially misunderstood your question.

Comment: .parse doesn't care what rule it starts with and will anchor the starting rule in the same way no matter its name.