# When is white space really important in Perl6 grammars?

Tags: whitespace, grammar, raku

can someone clarify when white space is significant in rules in Perl 6 grammars? I am learning some by trial and error, but can't seem to find the actual rules in the documentation.

Example 1:

```
rule number {
    <pm> \d '.'? \d*[ <pm> \d* ]?
}

rule pm {
    [ '+' || '-' ]?
}
```

Will match a number `2.68156e+154`, and not care about the spaces that are present in `rule number`. However, if I add a space after `\d*`, it will fail.
(i.e. `<pm> \d '.'? \d* [ <pm> \d* ]?` fails).

Example 2:
If I am trying to find literals in the middle of a word, then spacing around them are important. I.e., in finding the entry `Double_t Delta_phi_R_1_9_pTproj_13_dat_cent_fx3001[52] = {`

```
grammar TOP {
    ^ .*? <word-to-find> .* ?
}
rule word-to-find {
    \w*?fx\w*
}
```

Will find the word. However, if the definition of the rule `word-to-find` is changed to :
    `fx`
or  `\w* fx\w*`
or  `\w*fx \w*` then it won't make a match.

Also, then definition `'[52]'` will match, while the definition `'fx[52]'` will not.

Thanks for any insight. A pointer to the proper point in the documentation would help greatly!
Thanks,

Comment: I recommend using `token` instead of `rule`, and adding `<.ws>` manually.

Comment: @BradGilbert is your recommendation for this specific case or intended to be more general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can someone clarify when white space is significant in rules in Perl 6 grammars?

When `:sigspace` is in effect.

I'll provide a little more detail below. If you or anyone else reading this needs further details, let me know via comments and I'll expand further.

First, let's eliminate one possible source of confusion, namely the meaning of the words *rule* and *regex* in the context of Perl 6, before I provide the doc link.

The word *rule* may be used in either [a generic sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_6_rules) ("the regular expression, string matching and general-purpose parsing facility of Perl 6") or as a keyword (`rule`). Similarly, *regex* may be used to mean much the same thing as the generic *rule* or as a keyword (`regex`).

With that preamble out of the way, here's a link to [the `:sigspace` doc section](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex_adverb_%3Asigspace-regex_adverb_%3As-Sigspace).

Note that the `rule` keyword *implicitly* inserts a `:sigspace` such that it takes effect immediately following the first atom in the declared rule, and that the effect is lexical. See [@smls's answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41629369/1077672), especially the first two bullet points, for detailed discussion of these two important details.

You may also find [my answer to another SO question dealing with whitespace/tokenization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47732248/1077672) helpful.

Hth.

Answer (score 13):

In a `rule`, whitespace is turned into a `<.ws>` (that is, a non-capturing call to the `ws` token) except:

- At the start of the rule, before the first atom
- At the start of a `[` (group) or `(` (positional capture)
- After `||`, `|`, and `&`
- After a variable declaration (`:my $x = 'foo';`)
- After a code block
- After the `%` operator for introducing a separator
- After the `~` goal-matching operator
- After an internal modifier (such as `:i`)
- Inside of a construct like `$<var> = x`

Or, probably easier to remember, it will be inserted after any construct that could match some characters and after any zero-width assertion.

An important design goal in these rules is to never insert `<.ws>` somewhere that impedes Longest Token Matching. For example, consider `rule foo:sym<ba> { [ bar | baz ] }`, which is equivalent to `token foo:sym<ba> { [ bar <.ws> | baz <.ws> ] <.ws> }`. The default `ws` implementation is non-declarative (thanks to its use of `<!ww>`), meaning that it would break longest token matching both at the protoregex level were it inserted at the start of the rule, or at the alternation level were it inserted at the start of the group or after `|`.

Note that these rules only apply to `rule`, not to `token` and `regex`. They can be switched on at any point using `:s` and switched off using `:!s` in any of those, however (`rule` really just means "pretend there's a `:s` at the start").

Finally, the `ws` rule (which defaults to `token ws { <!ww> \s* }`) can be overridden in a grammar to define what whitespace means in the language being parsed.

Comment: Just for the record, I think there is currently a bug in rakudo that always interprets `<.ws>` as non-declarative, even if you override it in with a purely declarative token.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington thanks!  For clarification (perhaps I'm just bad with the Perl6 docs), what is the `token foo:sym<ba>` syntax? Specifically, is `:` an adverb here, or some kind of C++-like namespace? Similarly, what are the brackets `<>` doing the token's name? mille grazie

Comment: @dave It's protoregex syntax: a way of spreading members of an alternation over many tokens/rules instead (which further allows roles or subclasses to add to the alternation). See https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/Proto%20regexes.html for more.